# Background-color on checkbox doesn't set the color

Tags: css

I have an `<input type="checkbox" />`

I've managed to set things like the border color, but I seem not to be able to set the background-color. It just stays white.

Can anybody offer a solution, I've been looking on this site and others for an answer, but none that I've found work. This is an internal app that will be using the Edge Browser.

Comment: https://bun.js.org You can customise and check the code at the bottom of page here

Comment: Looks like your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css/49927978#49927978).

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi yes on the link you gave it sets `background: rgba(0,130,243,1)` setting it this way still didn't work for me

Comment: Is it also the same case for other browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be overriden by your browser's default settings. Have you tried adding `!important` to the `background-color` option?

If that doesn't help,  `appearance: none;` might help, but it removes completely default styles for your input, so you will have to style all the stuff like `:checked` mark etc.

E: If you just want to change the background color after checking the input, you can use `accent-color` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color)

Comment: The accent-color changes the color of the border. Not the input itself.

Comment: I worry you'll have to go for `apearrance: none` and start styling the whole input, I checked some of my previous projects and never found a way how to change background of input without it. The `accent-color` works only for checked capsule, that's why it changes color of the border.

Comment: Yes, apperance:none has done it...It;s knocked out other bits but hopefully I can sort it now.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure this will work or not but you can give a class name to input and try using :before and :after sudo selectors like

" .yourclassname:checked:after , .yourclassname:checked:before "

Answer (score 0):

### Just changing CSS won't work

Trying to set the background on input="checkbox" won't work when just given `"background:some_color"` because it has default values which will always override.

So we should use a label tag and a div tag to wrap the input tag, wherein input checkbox itself is hidden.

HTML

```html
<label class="contain">
 <input type="checkbox"/>
 <div class="fake-input"/>
</label>
```

CSS

```css
.contain *, .contain *::before, .contain *::after {
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}

.contain input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
}

.contain {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.contain input[type="checkbox"] ~ .fake-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 1.25rem;
    width: 1.25rem;
    background: rgba(0, 245, 248, 1);
    transition: background 250ms;
    border: 1px solid rgba(184, 194, 204, 1);
    border-radius: 0.125rem;
}

.contain input[type="checkbox"] ~ .fake-input::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: .45rem;
    top: .18rem;
    width: .25rem;
    height: .6rem;
    border: solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    transition: background 250ms;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.contain input:checked ~ .fake-input::after {
    display: block;
}

.contain:hover input ~ .fake-input,
.contain input:focus ~ .fake-input {
    background: rgb(10, 38, 43);
}

.contain input:focus ~ .fake-input {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(52,144,220,0.5);
}

.b-contain input:checked ~ .b-input {
    background: rgba(0, 130, 243, 1);
    border-color: rgba(0, 130, 243, 1);
}
```

If still are unsure about this, visit [Bun.js](https://bun.js.org). My answer is referred from there.